# SonarQube rules don't sync to both solution and project rulesets

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarlint

We're using the SonarAnalyzer.CSharp NuGet package and connecting to our SonarQube server (v 6.0) on this solution. I notice that if I turn on or off S103 (Lines should not be too long) on the server, and update in Team Explorer - SonarQube, both the solution.ruleset and project.ruleset files are updated.

However, if I change the setting for S125 (Sections of code should not be "commented out") only the solution.ruleset file is updated.

Why is that? How can we get the project.ruleset files to match the solution.ruleset files?

I also noticed you could go to the SonarQube server and search for `S103` to find that rule, but you cannot search for `S125` and find that rule. Are these different styles/types of rules?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue here. I can find the S125 when searching for the word in the 'Rules' tab of SonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody had set specific rules for the project, so those rules were no longer synced with the server.
I removed the project ruleset files and let SonarLint replace them from the server.